# ASP.NET Core - Viewing data error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have problem in viewing my data.

What I am trying to achieve in my page is that I place all of them in 1 view for viewing data, and CRUD operation using bootstrap.

I received this kind of error:

[image]

Also, it was suggested that I should use new() since it stated that I should create a new instance but I don't know where to place it. I tried to put it in my model like `public lstEmployee = new IEnumerable<Employee> { get; set; }` and it seems to not be working at all.

This is my code:

Model:

```
using PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.Models;
namespace prjPEMCOLoan.Models
{
    public class ModelEmployee
    {
        public IEnumerable<Employee> lstEmployee { get; set; }
        public Employee employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```html
@model prjPEMCOLoan.Models.ModelEmployee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Employees";
}
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

<p>
   <h3>List of Employees</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm openAdd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Add</button>
</p>

<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>ID Employee</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.lstEmployee)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fname)  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lname)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.EmployeeId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Details</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm openEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-emp-id="@item.EmployeeId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm openDiag" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-emp-id="@item.EmployeeId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var getAllEmployees = await _Context.Employee.ToListAsync();
    return View(getAllEmployees);
}
```

Comment: The error is quite clear: your model says it wants one ModelEmployee object, you give it a list of Employees. You need to create an instance of the model class, put the list in it and give that to the view.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, so I need to create a new instance of the model right? like this: `@model modelEmp = new MoelEmployee ();`?, Sorry I'm newbie...

Comment: You need to do that when returning the model from the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ViewModel:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Your ViewModel will have to be:

```
@model EmployeeViewModel
```

In your action you need to create the ViewModel and pass it to the view like:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var AllEmployees = await _Context.Employee.ToListAsync();

    var model = new EmployeeViewModel();
    model.Employees = AllEmployees;

    return View(model);
}
```

Also edit the view to match the new ViewModel:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Employees)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fname)  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lname)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.EmployeeId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Details</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm openEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-emp-id="@item.EmployeeId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm openDiag" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-emp-id="@item.EmployeeId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

Comment: Hi @Cristian, as you can see I put everything on ModelEmployee all necessary model that i will use inside a single view.  The code you posted didn't work on me, do you have any other idea on how to fix this? seems like I don't really understand the concepts on MVC yet since I'm still studying ASP.NET.